# No WiFi option on hp - realtek, RTL8723BE

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I have searched for solution to this problem on stack exchange. I do not find WiFi option in the top right corner, neither in the system setting.

I tried installing the driver from GitHub using `make`, `sudo make install`, `sudo modprobe rtl8723be`. They work all right and the repository in cloned onto my desktop. However, on running `sudo modprobe rtl8723be`

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8723be': Required key not available
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to WiFi? Or is the issue with the indicator only? If you are able to connect to WiFi, try [this answer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2251198) to get the indicator. If not able to connect to WiFi, try this: `sudo service network-manager start`

Comment: I am unable to connect to wifi even after sudo service network-manager start

Comment: I have even disabled UEFI Secure boot, to allow third party drivers.

Comment: Have you tried the answer mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules) ?